# Maintaining History of Commands in xv6

Tags: operating-system, xv6

I tried to maintain history of commands in xv6 which can be accessed using up and down arrow keys. I tried to maintain a history of 16 commands at time. I tried to start implementing it by starting from console.c but ended up getting confused. How should I do this ?

Comment: You should look at the `buf` array in `main()` function of `sh.c` file